# How can I reset the username Apple Transporter uses?

Tags: ios

I've been using Apple's Transporter app on my Mac to push our mobile builds to the app store. Recently, my company made account changes that requires 2FA with our live.com account. When I log into my apple account, I'm taken to a broken page at Microsoft. I've gotten around this with a secondary Apple Id. Unfortunately, today I launched Transporter, and it's doing the same thing. I have no way to enter in my secondary Apple Id. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the app, but there must be a config file somewhere that's saving my last login credentials.

Does anyone know how I can reset the app so I'm prompted for credentials again?

[image: Transporter 2FA Error]

Comment: If anyone else runs into this, I'm temporarily getting around this by launching the app as a different user via sudo in the console.

Comment: I'm suffering the same problem. No way to solve it unfortunately.